# MySQL only runs when Workbench connects to port 3306

Tags: mysql, docker, jdbc

I am running into an issue and I can't wrap my head around.

I want to use JDBC to connect to a MySQL database inside a docker container however I get this:

> Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection
>   to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.)

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/moviedb"
              auth="Container"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="user"
              password="pass"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false"/>
</Context>
```

I then download MySQL Workbench to make sure the MySQL was running on the port 3306. And it was running and my tables and data are being displayed. I went and refreshed my app and all of a sudden it displayed the data. Why is this happening? I feel like it has something to do with localhost vs 127.0.0.1 (or whatever it is). And this same project was working last week without the workbench, however, the only difference was I was not using a docker-compose file.

This is my docker-compose file for the container:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  database:
    container_name: data
    image: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "data"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pass"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
```

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

I forgot to metion that when i first create the container with docker-compose up workbench does not connect to the database. only have i just the container down then do docker compose start does workbench connect to the server.

Comment: It could be that your database was taking time to boot up, while you tried to connect the application. Could you remove Workbench and try connecting from your app again?

Comment: I have waited for like 10 minutes for it to start up still nothing.

Comment: Well, your insert scripts were in action

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what the issue was my assignment required me to use an SQL file with 180,000 insert statements that is why it was taking so long. I had to manually change them to be only one insert statement with multiple values.